# "in the X way" or "the X way"?

Tags: articles

Both the following sentences sound the same to (non-native) me.

"Start your computer scientist career by learning to program the OOP way."
"Start your computer scientist career by learning to program **in** the OOP way."

Should "in" be used before "the way"? Is there any other issue with any of the two sentences?

Note: OOP is an acronym for Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: We don't proofread marketing material, but I'd skip the *in*.

Comment: The use of *in* is possible here, but it does not sound idiomatic (as in, the way natives speak).